# Classification of unit group of a maximal order of a quaternion algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

Let $B$ be a definite quaternion algebra and $O$ a maximal order of $B$.
In proposition 5.3.1. of Vigneras' "The arithmetic of quaternion algebra",
the author classifies $O^*$.
But there's no proof. How can we show it?

I think that the point is theorem 1.3.7. in this book, which classifies
finite groups of the division quaternion over the real numbers.

I know that for $ u \in O^*$, the order of $u$ is $2,4$ or $6$.
Hence by theorem 1.3.7., $O^*$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $2,4,6$, the dihedral group of order $4,8,12$, the "bilinear tetrahedral group", the "bilinear octahedral group", or the "bilinear icosahedral group".

How can we exclude the later 2 cases?
And how can we show that if the discriminant of $B/\mathbb{Q}$ is neither $2$ nor $3$, then $O^*$ is cyclic?
And how can we compute $O^*$ for the case that the discriminant is $2$ or $3$?

Comment: See John Voight's book.

Comment: @Kimball Thank you very much